# Unit testing of an apache mina client

Tags: unit-testing, apache-mina

I have a mina client whose connector is a NioSocketConnector. I have written integration tests of this client with real server. However, I could not find a way to do **unit tests**. For example, I want to test my custom decoder and encoder works correctly without opening a real socket. And, I want to test my messages are queued correctly in the buffer etc.

I found a DummySession class for testings but I am not sure if this class is enough for a complete unit testing of the client.

Mina suggests unit testing is easy with it so I really wonder how can I do this. Please help with your ideas or links to sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unit testing of encoder:

```
YourEncoder encoder = new YourEncoder();
ProtocolCodecSession session = new ProtocolCodecSession();
encoder.encode(session, message, session.getEncoderOutput());
// encoded message will be in session.getEncoderOutputQueue()
```

Unit testing of decoder:

```
//Prepare an IoBuffer which will be decoded, say buf
YourDecoder decoder = new YourDecoder();
ProtocolCodecSession session = new ProtocolCodecSession();
decoder.decode(session, buf, session.getDecoderOutput());
//decoded message will be in session.getDecoderOutputQueue()
```